# Close the command prompt window programmatically

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I have a set of commands in batch file which is used to run the JAR file.It is working perfectly.

After running the program, the command prompt window doesn't get closed. If I manually close the window, then the application closes as well.

So I want to close the command window without affecting the application.

thanks in advance.

Comment: use `exit` at end of your `BAT` file.

Comment: Is your application a console program?

Answer (score 0):

Either use exit or make a new method to go to and have nothing in it. The exit way is better though. :)

Answer (score 0):

My psychic debugging powers tell me you're launching the JAR file using a `java` command instead of a `javaw` command.

Use `javaw` instead and the command window will close when the batch file exits.